# Efficient for loop in python

Tags: python

I want to write a for loop in python which iterates for example like 111, 112, 113, 114, 121, 122, 123, 124, 131,.. up to 444. Is there an efficient way to do so?

I tried to convert between decimal and base 4 system but is there a better way to do so?

Comment: DO you mean `range(111, 445)`?

Comment: no i dont want numbers like 115, 116, 117. it should only iterate to 4 and start over again

Comment: Why dont you just make a list since its just 16 numbers you need?

Comment: it is only an example, it could be up to one million positions (11.....1 to 44....4) and it is unefficient to iterate through numbers i dont need.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> for k in chain.from_iterable(range(i+1, i+5) for i in range(110, 450, 10)):
...     print(k)
...
111
112
113
114
121
122
123
124
131
132
133
134
141
142
.
.
.
423
424
431
432
433
434
441
442
443
444
```

Answer (score 0):

SO like this:

```
[ i for i in range(111, 445) if '0' < str(i)[-1] < '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```py
[ i for i in range(111, 445) if 0< i%(i-i%10) <5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a range of integers to base 4 using [`base_repr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.base_repr.html) from `numpy`:

```
import numpy


for i in range(64):
    print(int(numpy.base_repr(i, base=4)) + 111)
```

**Output:**

```
111
112
113
114
121
122
123
124
131
132
133
134
141
142
143
144
211
212
213
214
221
222
223
224
231
232
233
234
241
242
243
244
311
312
313
314
321
322
323
324
331
332
333
334
341
342
343
344
411
412
413
414
421
422
423
424
431
432
433
434
441
442
443
444
```